# Android downloadManager PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK time

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I looked everywhere for this and couldn't find, 
I'm using Android DownloadManager, during a file download I'm disabling the WIFI and Mobile data so there is no internet connection, The downloadmanager goes into Status: STATUS_PAUSED and reason: PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK,

How many minutes will it wait until it fail? or stop permanently...?
I've waited for an hour and it still paused and waiting for network...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the android documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

> The download manager is a **system service** that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and **retrying 
>   downloads afterfailures or across connectivity changes and system reboots**.

As it is a system service, it depends on the android internals to make a call when to stop it and as your download is already enqueued, it shall try downloading again once restarted, till the staus is either [STATUS_SUCCESSFUL](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java#STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) or STATUS_FAILED.

Comment: so it will never stop? and the responsibility to stop it is mine?

Comment: Yes. When you [DownloadManager#enqueue] your request, an id[long] is returned. Keep track of that and query[DownloadManager.Query] using it accordingly to check for the status, number of byte downloaded etc and handle for the appropriate cases[DownloadManager#remove may be].
May I know what is your requirement in detail?

Comment: I'm downloading some apk's from my app and I wanted to know if the DownloadManager will fail if the network unavailable for too long...

Comment: When will the download manager retry? Is there a specific interval or does the timing depend on the android internals as well?

Comment: it does not retry to download the apk when it PAUSED_WAITING with me, I am trying to download an apk to make auto-update, any one can help